# Property does not exist on type (2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting the typescript error `Property 'UPDATE_COLUMNS' does not exist on type 'DimensionAction'.ts(2339)` Even though you can see it is defined right above.

I'm using VSCode. I'm wondering if this is a bug with my IDE. I've run `yarn lint` and the syntax everywhere else in my code is totally fine.

[image: Code bug]

```
export enum DimensionAction {
    UPDATE_ROWS = 'update_rows',
    UPDATE_COLUMNS = 'update_columns',
}

const dimensionReducer = (state: Dimension, action: DimensionAction): void => {
    switch (action) {
        case action.UPDATE_COLUMNS:
            break
        case action.UPDATE_ROWS:
            break
        default:
            throw Error('Must pass action')
    }
}
```

Why isn't this code valid Typescript?

Comment: Q: Why not just "enum DimensionAction {}"?  Why add "export"?  And typically, your case statements would be `case DimensionAction.UPDATE_COLUMNS:`, not "action".

Comment: It should be that, I was just messing around trying to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the specific enumeration on the enum type itself.

```
case DimensionAction.UPDATE_COLUMNS:
```

Also, there is no need for a separate case for `UPDATE_ROWS`; it can just be handled in `default`. `action: DimensionAction` does not allow for `action` to be `null`, `undefined`, or anything other than one of the `DimensionAction` enum values.

Comment: Oh man. It's been a long day... Thank you